# snapkit do not support float type?

Tags: swift

snapkit do not support float type? how to solve the following situations

```
var backView: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    backView = UIView()
    self.view.addSubview(backView)

    backView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(100)
        make.height.equalTo(0.5)
        make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(30)
        make.right.equalToSuperview().offset(-30)
    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    print("height == \(backView.bounds.height)")
}
```

i expect height == 0.5,but the actual output 0.6666666666666666

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question, with information about the heights value being `0.6666666666666666` instead of the preset `0.5`

This information might make it a bit easier to help you out!

Don't give up on SnapKit, it's the best framework Ive ever discovered next to SwiftUI when it comes to UI.

Looking forward to attempting to help you here!

Comment: @nerohero are you using .labeled to debug?